# Efficient Way To Combine Items Within List of List

Tags: python

Many solutions I have run across use a slice of the list and join the items together. Rather, I would like to merge any two arbitrary items in a list together.

Given the example:

```py
a = [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

After merging items 1 and 3, the list would become:

```py
a = [[1], [2, 4], [3]]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in Python?

**Note**: The order does not need to be maintained. I just want to merge any two arbitrary items within a list.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pop()` to remove an element from the list, and `extend` to combine it with another element.

```
a[1].extend(a.pop(3))
```

This should work even if the element you're appending is earlier in the list, because `a[index]` is evaluated before `a.pop(index)`, so the array indexes haven't been adjusted yet.

Comment: I was thinking this too. Unfortunately, this solution would be O(nk) where "n" is the number of elements within the list and "k" is the number of elements within a specific list inside of a list.

Comment: No it's O(n+k).

Comment: Yes, sorry. Forgot the "+"

Comment: You're not going to get any better than that. Removing a list element is O(n), concatenating lists is O(k).

Comment: If you need something more efficient, don't use lists in the first place.